# How do I enable Progress report for Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops

Sprint 156 update rolled out Progress report in preview (should be an option between Test plans* and Parameters) but I can't seem to find where to enable it. I have turned on all my previews and still don't see it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops it should be available by clicking on `Progress report` under `Test Plans`.